# get category and sub category list of top menu in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress-rest-api

I am very new in WordPress and I have to create an API to get a list of category and it's subcategory of top navigation in WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wp_get_nav_menu_items( string $menu )

$menu = 
(string) (Required) Menu name, ID, or slug.
```

you can use this function to print out all the menu item with submenu

Comment: I am using the same function but it gives me all menu object in the same row, it doesn't give me the list of the subcategory in the same object if it has the subcategory.

Comment: the subcategories will come with menu_item_parent id , and the parent menu will have 0 as menu_item_parent